# Where can I find widgets for Unity?

Tags: 14.04, unity, widgets

I want to class up my desktop with various widgets that tell me network bandwidth hdd usage during r/w and real time memory usage just to name a few.  What a good way to go about that?

Comment: This isnt about "application indicators"

Comment: Desktop, not panel, close voters...

Answer (score 1):

1. System load indicator in the software center
   (sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload)
2. Conky
   (sudo apt-get install conky)